# Adobe Reader needs to be repair or remove(Elementary OS)

Tags: elementary-os

I need to uninstall Adobe Reader version 9.5.5-1. I got this error "Items cannot uninstalled or removed ..." I'd already tried sudo dpkg --purge adobereader-enu and still failed. Here is the detail:

---

```
Unpacking acroread-bin:i386 (from .../acroread-bin_9.5.5- 1precise1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-  1precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite  '/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/mozilla/prefs.js',   which is also in package  adobereader-enu:i386 9.5.5
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of acroread:
acroread depends on acroread-bin; however:
Package acroread-bin is not installed.

dpkg: error processing acroread (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: Does it help to remove the package using `dpkg -r adobereader-enu` before trying to install `acroread-bin`?

Comment: I got a warning on the terminal "there's no installed package matching adobereader-enu"

Comment: See Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since we tested the first error in comments, and there is no package, lets try the second:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of acroread:
acroread depends on acroread-bin; however:
Package acroread-bin is not installed.
```

Lets follow [Step 2 from Elementary's Community Q and A](http://elementaryos.org/answers/top-things-to-do), which states:

> 2) Install important and additional packages and repositories
>
> I always install Synaptic, dconf, gksu, leafpad and Gdebi as they are
>   not installed as default and in some cases programs such as synaptic
>   and gdebi provide a superior experience than the default software
>   centre. I also install an alternative browser such as Google Chrome
>   (this can be downloaded from their website and an office suite.

While I tend to disagree with adding Ubuntu Repositories here, I do agree with adding [Synaptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)) or [Gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gdebi/) because of the added dependency checking.

### Hunch

The file `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/mozilla/prefs.js` has been installed by another package that performs the same function that the Adobe Reader you want.  Since we can't tell what that package is, we need to use a tool with dependency checking, in order to see what that package is, then uninstall that package and then install the newest Version of Adobe Reader.

---

### Steps

1. Open a terminal; `sudo apt-get install synaptic gdebi`
2. Optional: Add A repository: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. Open Applications Menu > System > Synaptic.
5. Search for Adobe.  If anything similar to reader is installed, highlight the package, choose 'Mark for Uninstall'.
6. In the terminal from step 1, `sudo gdebi ../acroread-bin_9.5.5- 1precise1_i386.deb`

Post the results in your original question.